# ios navigation stack using storyboard segue

Tags: ios, user-interface, animation, segue, transition

I have three view controllers:

**messagesVC**: doesn't have navigation controller a chatting room

**viewControllerA**: has navigation controller and directs to messagesVC

**viewControllerB**: has navigation controller and directs to messagesVC

All three view controllers have their own storyboard for organization purposes. Right now, I created a storyboard segue to move from vcA or vcB to messagesVC. 
I want to be able to put messagesVC on either vcA or vcB each time it's shown so that push view controller animation would work instead of presenting messagesVC modally.  How would I achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In situation when you have segue in storyboard, choose the type of it 'show'. 
When your messageVC is in another storyboard, you should load it like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "VCAStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("messageVC") as! MessageVC
```

Then push it like this:

```
nvaigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

This will do the job.

Comment: I've tried that, but self.navigationController returns nil, and therefore doesn't perform any action. Any idea?

Comment: You said it has nvaigationController

Comment: Then if not, select your vc in storyboard, click Editor in menu -> Embed in -> nvaigation controller

Comment: I realized I was instantiating a UIViewController from another view instead of the embedded navigationController. Solved the problem. Thanks!